# ParseError when using a Token with AJAX and ASHX handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, token

I just tried to use a token that I generate on the handler and return to the client-side for authentication purposes. (Purpose: Authenticating all requests with the token, other than the first authentication step)

I tested and the client-side **does** get token, but the described error with the "parsererror" status and "Unexpected Token T" syntax error are given when trying a method involving authentication by token.

**Code to GENERATE the token which is working well**

```
        byte[] time = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToBinary());
        byte[] key = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        string _token = Convert.ToBase64String(time.Concat(key).ToArray());
```

**AJAX CODE to send request for a test-request**

```
function test() {
        var jsonParam = { token: _token , type: "check" }
        $.ajax({
            url: "Test.ashx",
            type: "post",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonParam),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {

                document.getElementById('eCode').innerHTML = response.eCode;

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responeText + "\r\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\r\n" + "Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });

    }
```

**Server code to respond to this AJAX request**

```
if (postType == "check")
    {
        // (dict is the deserialized received JSON, a dictionary of [string, object]

        string _token = dict["token"] as string;
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(_token);
        DateTime when = DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt64(data, 0));
        if (when < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12))
        {
            // Too old
            context.Response.Write(new Code { eCode = "old" });
        }
        else if (when > DateTime.Now.AddHours(1))
        {
            // Impossible
            context.Response.Write(new Code { eCode = "impossible" });
        }
        else
        {
            // Good
            context.Response.Write(new Code { eCode = "Time: " + when.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") });
        }


    }
```

And the following error is received: parsererror, Syntax Error of "unexpected token T". This error comes on the client side alert
Couldn't find anyone with the exact same problem.

Comment: Where do you get the error? Client or Server? What line of code?

Comment: Error comes from the alert of the client side

Comment: And what does it give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON that is returned by the generic handler is not well formed or not even JSON. Can you check the output of the handler by setting the `dataType` property to `text`? Like this: `dataType: "text"`

Comment: You are right, I just forgot to Serialize the "Code" objects, what a stupid mistake! Thank you.